# I have a conflict in my CSS. How do I find out where this conflict is in the bootstrap to fix?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, nav

I've found that there is a conflict that makes my original navigation bar stop working. How do I resolve this? From trial and error, the code conflict is from the link that I have highlighted below. At this point I am not sure how to work out where the conflict is within this. Does anyone have any guidance?

The below path is the path that allows my table of content to work.

Table of content code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="gallery col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <h2 class="text-uppercase">Portfolio</h2>
        </div>

        <div align="center" class="container gallery-filter">
            <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="all">All</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="PHP">PHP</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="JavaScript">JavaScript</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="CSS">CSS</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="MySQL">MySQL</button>
        </div>
        <br/>


<?php foreach ($portfolio as $project){ ?>
            <div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 <?php

            //turn technologies into an array to loop through 
            $string = $project->technologies; 
            preg_replace(' ','',$string);
            $array = explode(',',$string);
            $filter = "";
            foreach($array as $filter){
                echo "filter " . $filter . " ";
            } 
            ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $project->image1 ?>" alt="<?php echo $project->title ?>" class="img-responsive img-gallery border border-info">
                <div class="middle-gallery">
                    <div class="text-gallery">
                    <p class="uppercase"><?php echo strtoupper( $project->technologies ) ?></p>
                     <a href="?controller=portfolio&action=read&projectID=<?php echo $project->projectID; ?>" ><span class="button showmore">Find out more!</span> </a>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Navigation bar code:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light m-0 p-0">
                <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand "><img id="logo" src = "#" alt='#'></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon col-md-3 col-sm-2"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link menu" href="index.php">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link menu" href="?controller=portfolio&action=readAll">Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
<!--                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link menu" href="?controller=pages&action=about">Contact</a>
                        </li>-->
                        <li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block"><a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img class="nav-social" src="#" alt="Instagram social icon"></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block"><a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img class="nav-social" src="#" alt="Pinterest social icon"></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block"><a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img class="nav-social" src="#" alt="Twitter social icon"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

Comment: If you use Chrome, you can use the Chrome Debugger to see the inheritance of styles.In Chrome, right-click on the navbar and Inspect or F12, Elements tab to see the HTML as it is laid out. If you select your navbar there should be a 'Styles' section.

Comment: Thanks @AlanCheung . Is there a way of over riding it, or is there a better fix that I should be actioning?

Comment: Without looking too heavily (because I really dislike CSS), the best solution for fixing overridden CSS rules is to make your defined rules more specified (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp). If these are CSS rules from Bootstrap, then it would require a deeper dive to see why. Apologies for the non-answer answer, I just wanted you to have another tool to help debug.

Comment: That's OK. Understanding how to deepdive into it myself is a really helpful thing in itself. Thank you for your guidance - I'll keep digging!